# While git show--name--only provide multiple filenames in grep statement

Tags: git, groovy, grep

I want to look at the latest commit and determine if there were any changes made to files in the following file or filename. Respectively apiproxy (folder) or edge.json (filename)

I'm running the following code (*the steps.sh is some library specific thing the company uses. It's just a shell command):*

```
if((steps.sh ('git show --name-only HEAD | grep "apiproxy"')) || (steps.sh ('git show --name-only HEAD | grep "edge.json"'))){
                        echo "latest commit was a change to either edge.json or apiproxy"
}
```

When above executes while the latest changes were only made to match the first condition, the second condition will fail. In my thinking the `||` in between should prevent this from happening.

This is the first problem I'd like to solve. Evaluate both conditions and don't exit with exit code 1 when one of these fail.

Secondly I would like to put the `||` conditions in a single grep command if possible. I've tried the following to no avail:

```
git show --name-only HEAD | grep "edge.json | apiproxy"
```

Any pointers?

UPATE:

So with some help from 0andriy I've figured out that I want to use `git show --name-only "filename1" "filename2"`
Now my remaining question is: How can I put an or condition in the `git show` e.g. `git show --name-only "apiproxy" || "edge.json"`?

Comment: You need simple one: `git show ... -- file1 file2 ...` No `grep` is needed at all. Just list all your files in the command line.

Comment: can you elaborate? If I do `git show --name--only HEAD -- "apiproxy" "edge.json"` I get unrecognized argument. Should it be `git show --name--only HEAD | "apiproxy" "edge.json"`

Comment: So it should be git show "filename1" "filename2"

Comment: Of course, it should be `--name-only`. Note the one dash in between. `git show --name-only HEAD -- edge.json apiproxy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although above answers were quite helpful in pointing me towards the right direction, the solution to my problem is as follows:

`git show --name-only "filename1" "filename2"`

This outputs the specified filenames to which changes have been made in the `HEAD` state

The or statement is not helpful because it (obviously) stops at the first encounter of any match in the condition and I want to look for all matches.

Answer (score 1):

```
git show HEAD --name-only --pretty="" |grep 'apiproxy\|edge.json'
```

UPDATED. Restrict to exact file names

```
git show HEAD --name-only --pretty="" |grep '^apiproxy$\|^edge.json$'
```

Comment: `grep 'apiproxy\|edge.json'` or `grep -E 'apiproxy|edge.json'`

Comment: Watch out for partial matches when using grep expressions. Probably not a big problem here, but what if there's a file named `noapiproxyhere`? :-)

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon Is the use of HEAD necessary? Doesn't it only evaluate HEAD if you don't provide this option?

Comment: True, HEAD is not needed